# express redirect got response 304 and do nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

frontend is react and request to server use Fetch .

code like this .

```
        fetch(`/ONETOWN/LARK/PACKAGE/STOCKOUT/LOAD_LIST_BY_TELL`,{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(info)
      })
```

the backend(server) code like this,cookie expired,so i hope redirect to unauthorized page .

```
    static authentication(req,res) {
    if(this.verifyCookie(req,res)) {
        return true;
    }   
    //res.status(401).end();

    res.redirect('/#/page/unauthorized');

    return false;
}
```

[my Web don't redirect to the path i want,still stay the original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwvFw.png)

if Redirect change to Location method
res.location('/#/page/unauthorized').end()

got response 200

[got response 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVJT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you are using a `fetch` call to make an HTTP call, so your browser is not making a request, so it knows nothing that it needs to open a different page.

The solution is to check the response of your `fetch` call and make a redirect to the different page if needed.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Ayzrian, i have change my code logic to fix this problem .   you are right , i shoud do redirecting in frontend , check server response's status(401) , code like this .

```
enter code here
fetch(`url`,{
     method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(info)
      })
    .then(res => Authentication(res))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {

    }).catch((e) => {
        if (e.status === 401) {
            console.log(e);
            window.location="#/page/unauthorized";
        }
    });
};
```

.......................

```
    export const Authentication  = (res) => {
  if (res.ok) {
      return res;
  } else {
      return Promise.reject({
        status: res.status,
        statusText: res.statusText
      });
  }
}
```

................

```
static authentication(req,res) {
    if(this.verifyCookie(req,res)) {
        return true;
    }   
    res.status(401).end();
    //res.redirect('/#/page/unauthorized');  not works 

    return false;
}
```